# get values of checkbox group

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, checkbox

I have a form that contains `radio groups` and `checkboxe groups` as well, each `checkbox group` / `radio group` has a unique name.

In my `Servlet` I tried to get all checked values for those `radio groups` and `checkbox groups`.

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
Enumeration<String> requestParameters = request.getParameterNames();

while (requestParameters.hasMoreElements()) {
    String paramName = (String) requestParameters.nextElement();
    out.println("Request Paramter Name: " + paramName
              + ", Value - " + request.getParameter(paramName));
 }
```

When I select multiple `checkboxs` in a `checkbox group` I only get one value.

For example, I have this `checkbox group` :

```
<ul class="data-list-2">        
    <li>
       <div class="icheckbox_square-aero">
          <input style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;" name="question_1" class="required" value="Mise en page d’un texte" type="checkbox">
       </div>
       <label>Mise en page d’un texte</label>
    </li>

    <li>
       <div class="icheckbox_square-aero">
          <input style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;" name="question_1" class="required" value="Compilation d’un texte" type="checkbox">
       </div>
       <label>Compilation d’un texte</label>
    </li>

    <li>
       <div class="icheckbox_square-aero">
          <input style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;" name="question_1" class="required" value="Présentation d’un texte sous forme de diaporama" type="checkbox">
       </div>
       <label>Présentation d’un texte sous forme de diaporama</label>
    </li>

    <li>
       <div class="icheckbox_square-aero">
          <input style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;" name="question_1" class="required" value="Edition d’un texte" type="checkbox">
       </div>
       <label>Edition d’un texte</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I checked the last three `checkboxs`, I only get one value as the following :

> Request Paramter Name: question_1, Value - Compilation d'un texte

I googled about this, and I found that I must add a `[]` after the name of each `checkbox group`, but when I tried that, this is what I got :

> Request Paramter Name: question_1[], Value - Compilation d'un texte

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking multiple checkbox in form will give you values in String array form. You will have to use [request.getParameterValues()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29) inorder to get all values that you have selected in an String array.

Your sample could be like:

```
String[] questions = request.getParameterValues("question_1");
for(int i=0;i<questions.length;i++){
out.println(questions[i]);
}
```